# Application server и framework для backend'а веб-приложения под android

Tags: spring, framework, android, java, веб-программирование

Доброго времени суток.

Для не очень большого приложения под андроид требуется выбрать фреймворк.

Клиентская сторона только отправляет запросы на сервер и получает с него ответы, и ничего кроме этого не делает. Сервер обрабатывает запросы клиента, после этого обращается к базе данных, в качестве которой скорее всего будет выбрана MySQL, и из данных, полученных из базы, формирует ответ, который отправляет клиенту.

Возникли следующие вопросы:

1) При создании сайтов, запускается application server, например GlassFish или JBoss, который разворачивает проект, написанный с помощью какого-либо фреймворка. Нужно ли то же самое проделывать при написании приложения под андроид? Был бы очень рад, если кто-нибудь поделился бы материалом, поясняющим написание backend'а для веб-приложений на андроид.

2) Можно ли использовать веб-фреймворк, который используется при сайтостроении, например JSF, Spring? Или же фреймворк должен быть специально заточен под веб-приложение на андройде?

3) Собственно, какой backend фреймворк лучше всего подходит для этой задачи? Желательно что-нибудь opensource.

4) Вопрос о Spring for Android (projects.spring.io/spring-android). Поделитесь, пожалуйста, впечатлениями от использования этого фреймворка. Так же интересуют впечатления от использования Commonsware (github.com/commonsguy) , DroidParts (droidparts.org), Mortar (github.com/square/mortar) .

Если вопросы составлены непонятно или вы не понимаете, чего я хочу, а может я и сам не понимаю, то критика конечно приветствуется. Спасибо.

Comment: Нашел https://github.com/mttkay/ignition
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с ним?

Answer (score 1):

Пишите на том что лучше знаете, по сути вам надо просто отдавать клиенту данные json/xml (лучше json), как вариант [Django REST framework](http://habrahabr.ru/post/160117/)

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Как я понял, вы ответили на третий вопрос. А что, например, с первым вопросом? В гугле по запросу android application server ничего внятного не нашел.

Comment: Почти не работал с java ee, хотя по сути ответ тот же ─ что лучше знаете то и используйте, клиенту все равно на чем у вас написан сервер.